# Capacitor ionic vuejs android app not working in real device

Tags: android, vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have create ionic vuejs app used node server to consume api and i have use capacitor for building android application,android application build successfully and run in emulator api also working fine,but when i tried to run in actual device it gives me

`E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/js/chunk-vendors.784abd06.js - Line 1 - Msg: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error`

this error,can anyone help me on this
I used axios for calling api.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3YuU.png)

Comment: I am facing same error, did you figureout what was going wrong ?
Works fine with ionic serve and capacitor reload